# Compare response of SOAP webservice

Tags: android

I have following response of Soap web service.How to compare sonucBilgisi to some string.

the response is parsed via `ksoap2`

```
anyType{sonucBilgisi=Basarili; uye=anyType{Adi=Test name; Soyadi=Test surname; AcilisKonusmasi=Sayın Emre AKKUŞ'un telefonu; MesguliyetNedeni=meshül; TelefonunAcilmasiniIstiyorMu=true; }; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like ksoap2. I'll put that in your question. 
You can get the value of each property with `getPropery` or `getPropertyAsString` method of the `SoapObject`:

```
yourSoapObject.getPropertyAsString("sonucBilgisi");
```

Comment: no dear it give me force close..while i am printing that value to log cat...more help plzzzzz

Comment: you have to be more specific. Post your source code and logcat. Also read the stackoverflow FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and get familiar how to ask question and what information you should provide when asking a question.